# tkinter canceling filedialog.askdirectory() freezes program

Tags: tkinter, python-3.8

I wrote a function for a button in tkinter which asks you for a directory path and shows you the choosen path instade of the button.

```
def savepathopt(): 

    savepath = filedialog.askdirectory() 

    if savepath:

        savepathbutton.grid_forget()

        savepathlabel = tk.Label(text = savepath)

        savepathlabel.grid(row=0, column =1)
```

But if you cancel folder selection it freezes the program for 5 seconds or more.
Is there a way to avoid the freeze?
If there is anymore code needed please let me know.

Edit:
This is the whole code i have problems with.

```
optionwindow = tk.Toplevel()

def savepathopt():

    savepath = filedialog.askdirectory()

    if savepath:
        savepathbutton.grid_forget()

        savepathlabel = tk.Label(optionwindow, text=savepath)

        savepathlabel.grid(row=0, column=1)

savepathbutton = tk.Button(optionwindow, text="Choose path", width=20, height=1, command=savepathopt)

savepathbutton.grid(row=0, column =1)

optionwindow.mainloop()
```

The rest of my program worked just fine without any problems or lag.

Comment: You posted code should not have the freeze issue.  It should be somewhere else.

Comment: In the edit I added now more of the code of my program, i left out the rest because those are only labels and i dont think they will be the problem.

Comment: I have tested your updated code and it still cannot reproduce your issue.